A question about Jordan Curve Theorem
I have a "separation of a surface" question.
Assume that $N^2$ is a connected regular surface in $\mathbb R^3$ containing an infinite funnel. Let $L$ be the boundary of the funnel in $N$, which is a circle. Does $N \backslash L$ have exactly two connected components?
Actually, I have encountered the following problem. We have $N^2$ a connected regular surface in $\mathbb R^3$ (we can also assume that it is complete) and we know that $N^2$ contains the funnel $D$ given by the rotation around the $Oz$ axis of the curve
$$
c(t) = \left ( (1 + t) ^{3/2} , 0,  \frac 3 2 \left ( \sqrt{t^2 + t} + 
\mathrm {log} \left ( \sqrt t + \sqrt {t+1} \right ) \right )\right ), \ t > 0.
$$
The boundary of the funnel in $N^2$ is the circle obtained when $t = 0$. The question is whether $N^2 \backslash \mathrm {cl} (D)$ is connected or not.

What do you think? You can start solving this problem by writing down the actual definition of a funnel and noting that an embedding in $R^3$ is irrelevant for this problem.

@MoisheKohan Thank you very much for your response. I have edited a more precise version of my question. Please have a look.

"We know that $N^2$ contains the funnel $D$". Do we know anything else about $N^2$? For example, $D$ is a connected regular surface that contains $D$. Do we know that $N^2 \ne D$?

I forgot to include earlier - the Jordan Curve Theorem doesn't really play a part here, nor is the fact that $D$ is a funnel of any real importance. The real issue is what you know about $N^2$.  You can replace $D$ with a disk, and the same question can be asked with the same answer. It depends on how the rest of $N^2$ relates to that disk. Without any more information about $N^2$, the number of components of $N^2 \setminus \text{cl}(D)$ could be anything from $0$ to $\aleph_0$.

Thank you for your response. I am sorry for the late reply. More precisely, we have: $N^2$ is a connected, regular (embedded) surface in $\mathbb R^3$ and $N \backslash \mathrm {cl} D \neq \emptyset$, where $D$ is an open funnel given above.
